# Why Set marginRight ( element.style.marginRigth= xxx) not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am setting margin-right of a div on window resize using javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
    function marginFunction(){
        let cardd= document.querySelector(".maincard");
        var stle = cardd.offsetWidth;
        let circle=document.querySelector(".card_circle");
        var ml=(400-stle)/10;
        circle.style.marginRight =  ml +"px";
        document.querySelector(".abc").innerHTML= circle.style.marginRight;
        
    }
    window.onresize=marginFunction;

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="col">
            <a class="maincard" href="IALA boyage.html">
                <div class="card transition">
                    <h2 class="transition">IALA Buoyage</h2>
                    <!--<div class="cta-container transition"><p>Insert some text here to show on hover</p></div>-->
                    <div class="card_circle transition"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div><div class="col">
            <a class="maincard" href="IALA boyage.html">
                <div class="card transition">
                    <h2 class="transition">IALA Buoyage</h2>
                    <!--<div class="cta-container transition"><p>Insert some text here to show on hover</p></div>-->
                    <div class="card_circle transition"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div><div class="col">
            <a class="maincard" href="IALA boyage.html">
                <div class="card transition">
                    <h2 id="abc" class="transition abc">IALA Buoyage</h2>
                    <!--<div class="cta-container transition"><p>Insert some text here to show on hover</p></div>-->
                    <div class="card_circle transition"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div
</body>
</html>
```

The 'marginRigth' function is working because the innerHTML is changing on resizing. However, the margin-right is not changing visually, I don't know why

Previously I has put the script just before the '' tag but then browser was throwing an error 'marginFunction' not defined.

The CSS is :

```
.transition {
        transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.3, 0, 0, 1.3);
    }
    
    .card {
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        height: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .card:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    
    }

    .card:hover .cta-container {
        display: inline;
        margin-top: 380px;
    }

    .card:hover .card_circle {
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: -130px;
    }

    .card:hover h2 {
        background: #3487f7;
        color: #fff;
        margin-top: 100px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .card:hover h2 small {
        color: #fff
    }

    .card:hover p {
        margin-top: 300px
    }

    .card{padding-left: auto; padding-right: auto;}
    .card_circle {
        background: url(iala.png) no-repeat center top;
        background-color: #3487f7;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        margin-top: -270px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 450px;

        ;
    }
    h2 {
        color: #3487f7;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-top: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .maincard{padding: 10px;}
```

In case the above mentioned snippets are not working,
[Here](https://codepen.io/predator79/pen/LYaQwNQ) is the codepen of whole webpage.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the right margin?

Comment: @ev div which is in the form of a blue block is biger than the parent div. I want it to stay in the middle of the parent so that it does not look unpleasant as it can be seen in codepen code. I can center it if the page is static, but I'm making responsive design and whenever the parent width changes due to viewport, the blue block gets shifted. Therefore I'm using JS to keep it in the middle by taking into account the width of the parent.  The inspiration for the design is from https://codepen.io/knolaust/pen/bNvZRQ?editors=0100 .   I just want to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not make a big change, I don't understand why it was not working before
The following code is giving the desired result, but now it is only changing marginLeft of the first element and not of all. I'm quite sure it's because of the data types or querySelector(s), I'll look into it

```
<script>
function marginFunction() {
    let cardd = document.querySelector(".maincard");
    let w = cardd.offsetWidth;
    let circle = document.querySelector(".card_circle");
    let ml = (450 - w) / 2; // Corrected calculation
    circle.style.marginLeft = "-" + ml + "px";
    document.querySelector(".abc").innerHTML = circle.style.marginLeft;
}
window.onresize = marginFunction;
window.onload = marginFunction; // Trigger on initial load
```

**APPLYING TO ALL ELEMENTS WITH SAME CLASS**

```
<script>
    function marginFunction() {
        let cardd = document.querySelector(".maincard");
        let w = cardd.offsetWidth;
        let circle = document.querySelector(".card_circle");
        let ml = (450 - w) / 2; // calculates margin required as per width of card
        
        //for creating new style rule so that all the cards are affected
        var sheet = document.createElement('style')
        sheet.innerHTML = ".card_circle {margin-left: -" + ml + "px}";
        document.body.appendChild(sheet)
    }
    window.onresize = marginFunction;
    window.onload = marginFunction; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a mistake in your JavaScript code. The issue is with the calculation of the ml (margin-left) value. Instead of subtracting the stle from 400, you should subtract it from the width of the card container. Additionally, the card_circle element has a fixed width of 450px in your CSS, which may affect the calculation.

```
<script>
    function marginFunction() {
        let cardd = document.querySelector(".maincard");
        let stle = cardd.offsetWidth;
        let circle = document.querySelector(".card_circle");
        let ml = (cardd.offsetWidth - stle) / 10; // Corrected calculation
        circle.style.marginRight = ml + "px";
        document.querySelector(".abc").innerHTML = circle.style.marginRight;
    }
    window.onresize = marginFunction;
    window.onload = marginFunction; // Trigger on initial load
</script>
```

added window.onload = marginFunction; to trigger the marginFunction on the initial load of the page. This ensures that the correct margin is set even when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Even with corrected calculations, using `margin-right` may not be an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Hoffmann  since 'stle = cardd.offsetWidth;'   in the corrected calculation you are subtracting the value from itself, making it zero, Can you provide the actual calculation you meant to show.

Comment: @evolutionbox The original method to centre the block was by using negative 'margin-left' but since I didnt have any knowledge of javascript I didn't want to play with negative vlalues, hence im using margin-right.

Comment: @evolutionbox I used negative marginLeft and it is working working correctly.

Comment: @Hoffmann my formula was correct and you correctly mentioned 450 should be used instead of 400